# Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, truffle-migration, mastering-ethereum

The warning is from running sample code from [Mastering Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/dev-tools.asciidoc#using-truffle-to-deploy-a-contract), I get the above error and it says

> Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.
>     function Migrations() public {

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because of a deprecated standard. In the file, Migrations.sol, replace the line:

```
function Migrations() public {
```

with:

```
constructor() public {
```

The line of code shown just above is a **constructor**, it runs on a contract's deployment, and it is used(as in the file in context) to save the contract owner's address(**msg.sender** varies based on who interacts with the contract).

This replaces the existing implementation of using a function with the same name as the contract to act as a constructor with a seperate *constructor* function.

Comment: It's wrong, it's not `function constructor` but simply `constructor`.